July 2024: Firebase phone OTP authentication suddenly stopped working for the Ionic Capacitor Android app
Everything was working fine until two days ago, now I'm getting a 400 Bad Request invalid-argument error when trying to authenticate using a phone number. The OTP is not being received. I'm using Angular 17, Ionic 7, Capacitor 5, Firebase 10.9, and Angular/fire 17. I don't think it's related to the code; it might be due to configuration changes or deprecations in Firebase, the Google console, or the Play Store. Authentication works fine on the website however, facing this issue only in Android native app. Could someone please guide me on this? I've been stuck on this for two days.
The SHA1 and SHA256 of the app signing key have already been added to the Firebase console. The google-services.json file has been downloaded and placed in the android/app folder.
